# Google play rejecting my apk because it contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: java, android, google-play, tracking

I am getting an error from Google Play console as

> Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and
> Network Abuse policy. We found your app is using a non-compliant
> version of apporio infolabs SDK which contains code to download or
> install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.

Link of apporio infolabs SDK is https://github.com/samirapporio/Apporio-Tracking-System/tags.

I added the following line in my `build.gradle` file,

```
implementation 'com.github.samirapporio:Apporio-Tracking-System:1.0.14'
```

Please help me if someone have already solve this problem.

Comment: _...app is using a non-compliant version of apporio infolabs SDK..._  Is there a newer version?

Comment: No, it's an old version. I've been using this ever since and my latest version of my app is being rejected because of this package